# localhost refused to connect while running Azure functions locally

Tags: javascript, visual-studio-code, azure-functions

I am trying to set up a basic Azure Functions Local Environment by following instructions [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/create-first-function-vs-code-node#run-the-function-locally), however, after reaching the [step](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/create-first-function-vs-code-node#run-the-function-locally) and try to run it `F5` when I attempt to access it from the browser using function URL `http://localhost:7071/api/azure_func_test` I get:

```
localhost refused to connect.
```

I haven't even changed anything, and it's all just basic code and configurations.

What is the reason for this error?

Comment: Hello @Maven, try this - if you do not have live server extension in VS Code, download it, restart the VS Code and check it

Comment: try with the different port number (i.e., from local.settings.json) and also could you please add the code of index.js file!

Answer (score 0):

If you don't start the server with the command prompt it can duplicate that exact error:

> local host refused to connect

, and to solve it, first close the terminal in vscode if it's open. then open the server in a command prompt from windows, (not under administrator privleges) then type:

`cd <yourAppsFolderAddress>` press enter,

`cd my-static-web-app` press enter,

`cd react-app` (there are more options available here than just react) press enter, then type

`npm install` press enter, then, finally:

`npm start` and press enter. The tab in the browser should now have the blue atom  icon and say React App (or vue, or whatever you chose) and display your app, on a side note it took a few seconds for it to load in the browser also.

Answer (score -1):

I tried to reproduce your issue by following steps :

- Created the azure function (Stack: Javascript, Http Trigger) in VS code.
- Executed the azure function using boiler plate code.

[image]

After executing the function, the function URL will work.

[image]

[image]

If the execution stops, then the function URL stops working as you can see, it is showing as "**local host refused to connect**".
Make sure your function is running when you are testing the function URL.